# ASP.Net Maintain a list of objects for a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an asp.net page which loads data from a (SQL) visual studio database file (.mdf).

The data is loaded into a list of User objects (List) which contain the user data obtained from the database. This data is then displayed in a ASP.net table with a check box in column one. This allows the person viewing the webpage to in theory select users via the check boxes.

I have an ASP.net button also on the same page which when clicked will cause a post-back and go through the table row's and correctly identify which rows have and have not been checked. I am able to get the user data at this point as the Page_Load event is fired and the database contents are re-loaded for the second time.

Obviously this could become quite expensive obtaining the full list of users on each Page_Load so I have started investigating using the IsPostBack variable which allows me to identify whether it is a button click or standard page load.

The problem I have when using IsPostBack is the database contents loaded into the List on the initial Page_Load event would now be equal to null as the call into the database would never occur. This is understandable expected behavior and my question is what would be the best way to preserve the contents of the list so the button click can access the data loaded from the database on the initial Page_Load, without having to do another database query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not user specific data that you are taking about store it in Cache.

[Asp.net Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If its use specific data store it in session.

[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Comment: As a new ASP.NET user, I ran into this same issue, and the answer indeed was to load the data on initial page load and store it in Cache, then on postback page load, retrieve it from the Cache.  This answer certianly helped me; +1.

Comment: it seems this is the correct answer, ultimately i went a different route

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest caching the result from the database and then doing your binding as usual.  There are other options such as storing it in the ViewState but that can lead to much bigger page sizes depending on the data (personally I'm not a fan of ViewState, but it is an option).

At the end of the day, there is a certain amount of data you need to make the page work, you can't get away from having to store & retrieve that data somehow, so it comes down to deciding what is the most maintainable (and expected) way that doesn't have unacceptable tradeoffs.  In my opinion that would be caching the database result, but it really depends on the application.

Comment: Ok thanks, its looking like i will use a slightly different approach. Passing the userid in a hyperlink as a get variable to another asp.net page instead of reading the checkbox values and posting back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a private variable inside your class?

```
private List<myObject> _data = null;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)                        
    {
        _data = loadDataFromDb();
    }
}

private void Button_Click()
{
    if(_data != null)
       //Do something with the data
}
```

-Updated: I think you can avoid postbacks this way, so you only load your data once.

Comment: I will try this though my current implementation is pretty much the same as this except i am using protected not private.

Comment: It's a pseudo code example, but shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to your code.

Comment: it looks more or less identical to my code which doesnt work except you have the object as private and mine was protected. This isnt ideal when you click the button the page reloads and you would ultimately make two database calls which is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok @Dizzle, I understand what you mean now, see the updated answer

Comment: again this is what i had, when i asked my original question the list _data is null in the button click function.

Comment: I also ran into this problem with an almost identical implementation to what this answer suggests; it simply does not work because the variable's state isn't maintained - that is to say that I think a new Page is created with each postback, so your variable is newly instantiated after a postback (I'm new to ASP.NET also and just learning this by trial and error).

Comment: By the way, for anyone else who runs into this issue, like the other answers suggest, your list can be stored in the Cache and reassigned; so... if (!Page.IsPostBack {//load your list from DB}) else {//load your list from Cache}.  That worked for me.